# Cannot load plugins in current version of Calibre

Tags: 11.10, plugins, calibre

The filter for loading downloaded plugins in Calibre seems to be broken.

The official [manual for creating plugins](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/creating_plugins.html) says that plugins should bi in zip format with the appropriate **init**.py file. However the filter on the GUI for loading plugins (Preferences -> Plugins (under advanced) -> Load plugins from file) puts up a filter for filetypes of type "Plugins" and doesn't display any files.  This seems to be an error in the configuration, but I do not know how to fix it.  I'm using the version of Calibre in the current Ubuntu release repositories (0.8.8), unity interface.  The problem has been documented [elsewhere](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=130897) and it suggests this has been fixed in the most recent version, but I'm not sure what the best solution is (e.g. I'd rather not use versions of packages setup outside the Ubuntu package manager that won't receive the automatic updates, etc).

Any suggestions for the best work-around?

Comment: I've found a command-line solution: calibre-customize -a path/to/plugin.zip, though I'd be happy to hear of other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> downloaded plugin file in Nautilus
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> in "Load plugins from file" dialog window

For now, it's only solution to do it in GUI without using command-line solution ...

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found a better workaround.

I opened the folder contents where the plugins were downloaded. I then chose the plugin I wanted and dragged it into the Calibre add-plugin-from-file dialog window. Voila! ALL the contents (i.e. all the other plugins as well) appeared in the Calibre dialog window. The "plugin" file-type filter also greyed out. This is obviously a Calibre bug.

Try it. Hope it works for you too.